# Centrifugal pressure of the inner core towards the outer core of the Earth

Tags: newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, pressure, planets, centrifugal-force

As we go towards the center of Earth the gravity weakens. Does that mean that due to absence of gravity the outer part of the inner core exerts a pressure against the inner part of the outer core of Earth as the inner core rotates very fast and feels a centrifugal force on their volume?

Comment: What do you mean  by "rotates very fast" ? Any rotational evidence relative to the rest of the Earth is inconclusive and if so is believed to be be very slight.

Comment: @AdrianHoward https://youtu.be/XXTEWQdu3aE

Comment: All of the info I have studied give 1 extra rotation every 400 to 1200 years,  https://www.nsf.gov/discoveries/disc_summ.jsp?cntn_id=100044&org=NSF

Comment: If you have found newer published studies please provide a link, I would love to hear newer info, thanks

Comment: I forced myself to watch the first minute of that YouTube video. I could not force myself to watch any further.